# Array state will be cached in iOS 12 Safari. Is it a bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, ios12

> ***Update at 2018.10.31***
>
> *This bug has been fixed in iOS 12.1, have a good day~*

I found a problem with Array's value state in the newly released iOS 12 Safari, for example, code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title>iOS 12 Safari bugs</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function ()
    {
        let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        alert(arr.join());

        document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function ()
        {
            arr.reverse();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Array.reverse()</button>
    <p style="color:red;">test: click button and refresh page, code:</p>
</body>
</html>
```

After refreshing the page, the array's value is still reversed. Is this a bug or a feature of new Safari?

---

Here is a demo page. Try to use it with iOS 12 Safari:
https://abelyao.github.io/others/ios12-safari-bug.html

Comment: Bug confirmed also in macOS 10.14 Mojave - https://i.imgur.com/ZJtJJC1.png

Comment: macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) with Safari Version 12.0 (13606.2.11) has the same issue. Array is still reversed after refreshing the page.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in Safari 12.0.1 (macOS), as well as in iOS 12.1.

Answer (score 276):

It's definitely a BUG! And it's a very serious bug.

The bug is due to the optimization of array initializers in which all values are primitive literals. For example, given the function:

```
function buildArray() {
    return [1, null, 'x'];
}
```

All returned array references from calls to `buildArray()` will link to the same memory, and some methods such as `toString()` will have their results cached. Normally, to preserve consistency, any mutable operation on such optimized arrays will copy the data to a separate memory space and link to it; this pattern is called [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), or CoW for short.

The `reverse()` method mutates the array, so it should trigger a copy-on-write. But it doesn't, because the original implementor (Keith Miller of Apple) missed the `reverse()` case, even though he had written many testcases.

This bug was [reported to Apple](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188794) on August 21. The fix [landed in the WebKit repository](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/235356/webkit) on August 27 and shipped in Safari 12.0.1 and iOS 12.1 on October 30, 2018.

Comment: Note: Safari 12.0 on Mac OS X also have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah it’s been fixed in the sources already, and shipped in Safari Technology Preview already. Try https://cdn.miss.cat/demo/ios12-safari-bug.html in Safari Technology Preview 65. You’ll find that it doesn’t have the bug.

Comment: I don’t believe the underlying cause of the bug is the result of an index mixup; instead, it seems to be caused by neglecting to check whether an object is immutable before modifying it. The slice issue may have a similar explanation, but it’s not the same but and won’t be fixed by the patch for reverse, as far as I can tell. You should consider opening a WebKit bug report for the slice issue.

Comment: @Zenexer You are right. I wrote this answer before I found the https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188794 and see the source code. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 76):

I wrote a lib to fix the bug.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-reverse-polyfill

[This is the code](https://github.com/fanmingfei/array-reverse-ios12):

```js
(function() {
  function buggy() {
    var a = [1, 2];
    return String(a) === String(a.reverse());
  }
  if(!buggy()) return;
  var r = Array.prototype.reverse;
  Array.prototype.reverse = function reverse() {
    if (Array.isArray(this)) this.length = this.length;
    return r.call(this);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Update at any time. Welcome to contribute.

Comment: @zephi, I guess that writing on length (`this.length = this.length`) will trigger Copy On Write, so will change the memory address of the array, and so will fix the behavior of `reverse`.

Answer (score 14):

This is a bug in [webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188794). Though this has been solved at their end but not yet shipped with iOS GM release. One of the solutions to this problem:

```
(function() {
  function getReverseStr() {
    return [1, 2].reverse();
  }

  var n1 = getReverseStr()[0];
  var n2 = getReverseStr()[0];
  // check if there is an issue
  if(n1 != n2) {
    var origReverseFunction = Array.prototype.reverse;
    Array.prototype.reverse = function() {
      var newArr = this.slice();
      // use original reverse function so that edge cases are taken care of
      origReverseFunction.apply(newArr, arguments);
      var that = this;
      // copy reversed array
      newArr.forEach(function(value, index) {
        that[index] = value;
      });
      return this;
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems not to be cached if the number of elements changes.
I was able to avoid this like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title>iOS 12 Safari bugs</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function ()
    {
        let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        arr.push('');
        arr.pop();
        alert(arr.join());

        document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function ()
        {
            arr.reverse();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Array.reverse()</button>
    <p style="color:red;">test: click button and refresh page, code:</p>
</body>
</html>
```